# ansible module os_keypair never returns the value of private_key

Tags: ansible, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-horizon

I would like to use the `ansible` module `os_keypair` to generate a ssh keypair with `openstack`. To do so I use the following code:

```
- name: create openstack ssh key pair
  os_keypair:
    name: my-key
    auth: my authentication parameters
    auth_type: password
    state: present
  register: key
```

When running that code starting from scratch i.e. no key previously generated, it works in the sense that the key is generated and uploaded in `openstack`.
However, I would need the private key in order to perform subsequent actions through ansible (e.g. `local_action` for copying the private key to a file). The module documentation says that the private key is available as one of the return value. When checking my return values I get the following:

```
"key": {
   "created_at": null, 
   "fingerprint": null, 
   "id": null, 
   "is_deleted": null, 
   "location": null, 
   "name": null, 
   "private_key": null, 
   "public_key": null, 
   "type": "ssh", 
   "user_id": null
}
```

which looks kind of puzzling to me. Is that normal behavior or is there something wrong with that module ?

[UPDATE]
Here is a complete playbook that reproduces that behavior:

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  become_user: ansible

  become: True

  tasks:

    - name: create openstack ssh key pair
      os_keypair:
        name: my-key
        auth:
          auth_url: http://cloudsrv1.ill.fr:5000/v3
          username: ansible-test
          password: 1234
          project_name: k8s
          project_domain_name: default
          user_domain_name: default
        auth_type: password
        state: present
      register: key

    - debug:
        var: key
```

Playbook executed with python3 as python interpreter.

Output:

```
TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "key": {
        "changed": true, 
        "failed": false, 
        "id": "my-key", 
        "key": {
            "created_at": null, 
            "fingerprint": null, 
            "id": null, 
            "is_deleted": null, 
            "location": null, 
            "name": null, 
            "private_key": null, 
            "public_key": null, 
            "type": "ssh", 
            "user_id": null
        }
    }
}
```

and however the key is generated as can be seen from the `openstack` snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me. Can you update this question with a playbook that successfully reproduces the problem for you?

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick feedback. I just added an update section to better show the problem

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I tested.  I'm using Ansible 2.8.4 with Python 3.7; you can see a completely successful run here: https://asciinema.org/a/39bdI6IZiIkksfhjSlyQ8Wsx7

Comment: @larsks looking deeper through the debugging mechanism (ANSIBLE_KEEP_REMOTE_FILES=1 + module explode mode), I could see that my return values dictionary is pruned of all its parameters in the line new_value = _remove_values_conditions(value, no_log_strings, deferred_removals) of basic.py module. However this still does not give me any reason why this happens to me and not to you.

Comment: @larsk could you please tell me which version of openstack package you are using ? Digging further, the problem comes from the `openstack.compute.v2.keypair.KeyPair` class which is based on a `dict` for which the special method `items()` returns `None` for all values. To get the _actual_ ones (e.g. private_key, public_key) ... the method `toDict` has to be used. The fact that this _special_behavior_ is not taken into account  in the generic `container_to_text` method of `ansible.module_utils.common.text.converters.py` module triggers the wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by `pip` installing the newest `openstacksdk` package (0.36).

Comment: Glad you figured it out!